# what is the same equivalent query in `rails console` with this sql ?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

SQL:

```
select * from user where room_id not in (select id from rooms);
```

what is the same equivalent query in `rails console`  with this sql?

ex:

```
User.all.each { |u| user.room }
```

(sorry, but this example is not correct.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User.where("room_id not in (select id from rooms)")
```

but you want this since it would be rather faster:

```
User.where("not exist (select id from rooms where id=users.room_id)")
```

that's the closest you can get.  There appears to be no way to create an Active Record query that translates to SQL `NOT()`.  A search on the subject returns a bunch of SO questions with much the same answer.

You could do something like

```
User.all.select { |u| !Room.find_by_id(u.room_id) }
```

But that could be less efficient again.

Comment: Calling `User.all` on a non-trivial data-set is extremely dangerous and shouldn't even be suggested as a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can translate it almost literally:

```
User.where('room_id not in (select id from rooms)').all
```

The `where` clause is quite flexible in what it accepts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are familiar with the `squeel` gem. It allows allows you to build very complex SQL-queries in a pure Ruby code. In your case it should be as simple as the following code (afer adding the `gem 'squeel'` line in your Gemfile and running `bundle install`):

```
room_ids = Room.select{id}; User.where{room_id.not_in room_ids}
```

Worth trying, isn't it?

Here's the [squeel's page](https://github.com/ernie/squeel).